# how do I raise DatastoreTimeoutException or/and DatastoreFailureException on JUnit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use Google appengine Java.

In my Junit tests, I want to raise the exceptions DatastoreTimeoutException and DatastoreFailureException. How can I raise throw exceptions ?

Answer (score 0):

In a JUnit test you can throw any exception that you are permitted to construct. Just be sure to mark your test as throwing that exception (or, as is more often the case, state that it can throw *any* exception).

E.g.

```
@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    throw new WhateverYouFancy("Hello, world!");
}
```

Or if you want to check that a specific exception has been thrown (i.e. because this would indicate test success) you would do the following:

```
@Test(expected=FancyException.class)
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    // do something that ought to trigger a FancyException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not really clear.

The Google Appengine server can generate DatastoreTimeoutException when the datastore does not respond and also DatastoreFailureException when the datastore throws an unknown exception.

In my Junit test, I want that the server throw these exceptions. Like using the capabilities of the server https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/capabilities/overview

I want to write like this in order to check that I catch these exceptions:

```
@Test 
public final void testDatastoreFailureException() {
    // config the datastore in order to throw the exception
    try {
        // do something using the datastore.
    } catch ( DatastoreFailureException e ) {
        fail("We do not catch the exception DatastoreFailureException");
    }
}
```